# Can I apply stars and bars when absolute value is present?

Tags: combinatorics

The question is

> The number of $5$-tuple integers $(a, b, c, d, e)$ that satisfy the inequality $$|a|+|b|+|c|+|d|+|e|\leq8$$
> is...

My first immediate thought was to use stars and bars, but I'm not sure if:

- it is applicable to inequalities,
- it works with absolute value.

Any suggestion would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It being less than or equal to 8 means you can break it into 9 cases of equality if that helps. i.e. solving $\sum |a_i| = n$ for $n\in\{0,...,8\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This response represents a highjacking of and an elaboration of the analysis in the answer of RobPratt.  Not only do I completely agree with his analysis, but when I was scratch-working on the problem, my analysis was nowhere near as elegant as his.

First see the comments immediately following RobPratt's answer.  In order to fully understand his analysis, the Math student's **intuition** must **first** be stretched.  The only way that I can see stretching the intuition is by slowly and carefully working through relevant examples.  These examples will illustrate the necessary concepts.

For Stars and Bars theory, the Math student should first see
[this article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) and
[this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

---

$\underline{\text{Example 1}}$

Consider the number of solutions to the following:

- $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k = n ~: ~n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$
- $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_k \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

Per the linked references, the number of solutions is $~\displaystyle \binom{n + [k-1]}{k-1}.$  The Math problem represented by the two bullet points above may reasonably be considered to be the $\color{red}{\text{standard normal form}}$ of a Stars and Bars problem.  That is:

- $x_1 + \cdots + x_k \color{red}{=} ~n,$ 
  rather than $~x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k \color{red}{\leq} n.$
- $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_k \in \color{red}{\Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}},$ 
  rather than $~x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_k \in \color{red}{\Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}}}.$
- There are certainly no $\color{red}{\text{absolute value}}$ signs involved.

The subsequent examples (below) are going to deal with the three bullet points above, one at a time.  To facilitate the illustrations, in *many* of the subsequent examples, $k$ will be specifically set to $5$.

That is, *many* of the subsequent examples will specifically involve the variables 
$x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5.$

Further, for illustrative purposes, in *many* of the subsequent examples, the *generic* constant $(n)$ will be replaced by an explicit value.

---

$\underline{\text{Example 2}}$

Consider the number of solutions to the following:

- $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_5 \leq 6.$
- $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_5 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

This may be converted into the $\color{red}{\text{standard normal form}}$ by creating the variable $f$ where 
$f = 6 - (x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_5).$  Note that under this constraint, $f$ is **forced** to be a non-negative integer.

So, the number of solutions to the problem presented at the start of Example $2$ is **the exact same** as the number of solutions to

- $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_5 + f = 6.$
- $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_5, f \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

Per Stars and Bars theory, the number of solutions to the problem presented at the start of Example 2 is therefore 
$\displaystyle \binom{6 + 5}{5} = \binom{11}{5}.$

---

$\underline{\text{Example 3}}$

Consider the number of solutions to the following:

- $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k = n ~: ~k,n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}}, ~k \leq n.$
- $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_k \in \color{red}{\Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}}}.$

The key to this problem is to **convert** it into *standard normal form* by the following change of variables: 
$y_i = x_i - 1 ~: ~i \in \{1,2,\cdots,k\}$.

Then, consider the problem:

- $y_1 + y_2 + \cdots + y_k = (n-k)~: (n-k) \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$
- $y_1, y_2, \cdots, y_k \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

Note that there is a **bijection** between the set of solutions to the problem presented at the start of Example 3, and the problem presented directly above.  Therefore, the number of solutions to the problem presented at the start of Example 3 is **the same as** the number of solutions to the problem presented directly above.

The number of solutions to the problem presented directly above, which is in standard normal form, is 
$\displaystyle \binom{[n-k] + [k-1]}{k-1} = \binom{n-1}{k-1}.$

Therefore, the number of solutions to the problem presented at the start of Example 3 is also 
$\displaystyle \binom{n-1}{k-1}.$

---

$\underline{\text{Example 4}}$

Now, things are going to get a bit *tricky*.  Instead of presenting only one problem at the start of this example, I am going to present a **pair** of problems:

**Problem 4.1**: 
Consider the number of solutions to the following:

- $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 3.$
- $x_1, x_2, x_3 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

**Problem 4.2**: 
Consider the number of solutions to the following:

- $|x_1| + |x_2| + |x_3| = 3.$
- $x_1, x_2, x_3 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

Per Stars and Bars theory, Problem 4.1 has $~\displaystyle \binom{5}{2} = 10~$ solutions.  These solutions are listed below, in the form of ordered triples $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$.

$(0,0,3), (0,1,2), (0,2,1), (0,3,0),$ 
$(1,0,2), (1,1,1), (1,2,0),$ 
$(2,0,1), (2,1,0),$ 
$(3,0,0)$.

For illustrative purposes, in order to **elegantly** compute the number of solutions to Problem 4.2, I am going to first **re-group** the $10$ solutions to Problem 4.1, as follows:

Line 1: $~(0,0,3), (0,3,0), (3,0,0).$ 
Line 2: $~(0,1,2), (0,2,1), (1,0,2), (1,2,0), (2,0,1), (2,1,0).$ 
Line 3: $~(1,1,1).$

Each Line 1 solution to Problem 4.1 may be used to generate exactly $2^1$ solutions to Problem 4.2.  This is because each Line 1 solution to Problem 4.1 has **exactly one** non-zero component.

That is, the Problem 4.2 solutions that correspond to the Line 1 solutions of Problem 4.1 are 
$(0,0,+3), (0,+3,0), (+3,0,0).$ 
$(0,0,-3), (0,-3,0), (-3,0,0).$

So, there are exactly $2 \times 3 = 6$ Problem 4.2 solutions that correspond to the $3$ Line 1 solutions to Problem 4.1.

Each Line 2 solution to Problem 4.1 may be used to generate exactly $2^2$ solutions to Problem 4.2.  This is because each Line 2 solution to Problem 4.1 has **exactly two** non-zero components.

For example, the specific Line 2 solution of 
$(0,1,2)$ 
generates the following **four** solutions to Problem 4.2:
$(0, +1, +2), (0, +1, -2), (0, -1, +2), (0, -1, -2).$

So, there are exactly $4 \times 6 = 24$ Problem 4.2 solutions that correspond to the $6$ Line 2 solutions to Problem 4.1.

Similarly, the Line 3 solution to Problem 4.1 may be used to generate exactly $2^3$ solutions to Problem 4.2.  This is because the Line 3 solution to Problem 4.1 has **exactly three** non-zero components.

So, there are exactly $8 \times 1 = 8$ Problem 4.2 solutions that correspond to the $1$ Line 3 solution to Problem 4.1.

Therefore, Problem 4.2 has a total of 
$6 + 24 + 8 = 38~$ solutions.

So, the **next step** is to (somehow) determine an elegant way of **specifically** computing the exact number of solutions to Problem 4.2.

With respect to the Line 1 solutions to Problem 4.1, consider the following **related** problem:

- $x_1 + 0 + 0 = 3, ~x_1 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}}$ 
  which converts to the Example 3 form of
- $\displaystyle x_1 = 3 ~: ~\binom{3 - 1}{1-1} = \binom{2}{0} = 1~$ solution. 
  The flaw in the above scenario is that it assumes that $x_1$ is the non-zero variable.  So, it overlooks the related equations: 
  $0 + x_2 + 0 = 3$ and $0 + 0 + x_3 = 3.$ 
  Since there are $3$ variables, and Line 1 involves solutions with exactly one non-zero component, the number of Line 1 solutions may be **elegantly** computed as 
  $\displaystyle \binom{3}{1} \times \binom{2}{0}~$ solutions. 
  Further, since each Line 1 solutions has exactly one non-zero component, the number of Problem 4.2 solutions that **correspond** to Problem 4.1 :: Line 1 solutions may be **elegantly** computed as 
  $\displaystyle 2^1 \times \binom{3}{1} \times \binom{2}{0}~$ solutions.

Now, with respect to the Line 2 solutions to Problem 4.1, consider the following **related** problem:

- $x_1 + x_2 + 0 = 3, ~x_1,x_2 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}}$ 
  which converts to the Example 3 form of
- $\displaystyle x_1 + x_2 = 3 ~: ~\binom{3 - 1}{2-1} = \binom{2}{1} = 2~$ solutions. 
  Since there are **exactly two** non-zero components involved in Problem 4.1 :: Line 2 solutions, the number of such solutions may be elegantly computed as 
  $\displaystyle \binom{3}{2} \times \binom{2}{1}.$ 
  Further, since each Problem 4.1 :: Line 2 solution has exactly two non-zero components, the number of Problem 4.2 solutions that **correspond** to Problem 4.1 :: Line 2 solutions may be **elegantly** computed as 
  $\displaystyle 2^2 \times \binom{3}{2} \times \binom{2}{1}~$ solutions.

Finally, with respect to the Line 3 solution to Problem 4.1, consider the following **related** problem:

- $\displaystyle x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 3, ~x_1,x_2,x_3 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}}
   ~: ~\binom{3 - 1}{3-1} = \binom{2}{2} = 1~$ solution. 
  Since there are **exactly three** non-zero components involved in the Problem 4.1 :: Line 3 solution, the number of such solutions may be elegantly computed as 
  $\displaystyle \binom{3}{3} \times \binom{2}{2}.$ 
  Further, since the Problem 4.1 :: Line 3 solution has exactly three non-zero components, the number of Problem 4.2 solutions that **correspond** to the Problem 4.1 :: Line 3 solution may be **elegantly** computed as 
  $\displaystyle 2^3 \times \binom{3}{3} \times \binom{2}{2}~$ solutions.

Putting all of this together, the number of Problem 4.2 solutions may be elegantly computed as

$$\left[2^1 \times \binom{3}{1} \times \binom{2}{0}\right]
+ \left[2^2 \times \binom{3}{2} \times \binom{2}{1}\right]
+ \left[2^3 \times \binom{3}{3} \times \binom{2}{2}\right]$$

$$= \sum_{r=1}^3 \left[2^r \times \binom{3}{r} \times \binom{2}{r-1}\right] = 6 + 24 + 8 = 38.$$

---

---

---

**Before** going forward, the Math student should go back and review each of the four examples above, **very carefully**.  These examples are **pointless** unless the Math student uses them to **significantly stretch their intuition**.

Assuming that that has been done, the initially posted problem, discussed below, may now be **elegantly** attacked.

$$|a| + |b| + |c| + |d| + |e| \leq 8 ~: ~a,b,c,d,e \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}. \tag1 $$

First, this gets converted into

$$|a| + |b| + |c| + |d| + |e| + f = 8 ~: ~a,b,c,d,e,f \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}. \tag2 $$

Then, (2) above gets converted into a family of equations, depending on how many of the variables $a,b,c,d,e$ will be non-zero.  Let $r$ be any element in $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}.$

Consider the family of equations represented by

$$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_r + f = 8 ~: x_1, \cdots, x_r \in 
\Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}}, ~f \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}. \tag3 $$

That is, you have that :

- $r = 0 ~: ~f = 8.$
- $r = 1 ~: ~x_1 + f = 8.$
- $r = 2 ~: ~x_1 + x_2 + f = 8.$
- $r = 3 ~: ~x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + f = 8.$
- $r = 4 ~: ~x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + f = 8.$
- $r = 5 ~: ~x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + f = 8.$

Suppose that $f(r)$ denotes the number of solutions to (3) above, for $~r \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$.

Then the desired computation is

$$\sum_{r=0}^5 \left[\binom{5}{r} \times 2^r \times f(r)\right].$$

This is explained as follows:

- First of all, you will have the scalar of $~\displaystyle\binom{5}{r}.~$  
  Similar to the analysis in Example 4, this scalar represents that of the **five** variables $a,b,c,d,e$, there are $~\displaystyle \binom{5}{r}~$ ways of selecting which of these five variables will be arbitrarily designated as the $r$ non-zero variables.
- Then, since there will be exactly $r$ non-zero variables involved, and since (2) above involves absolute values, you will have the **second scalar** of $2^r.$
  Again, if there is any confusion on this point, the Math student should go back and study Example 4 more carefully.

So, the **entire problem** has been reduced to **deriving** the formula for $f(r)$.  To do this, you must
dissect the problem presented in (3) above, very carefully.  It is *close to*, but **not exactly the same** as the problem discussed in Example 3.  The difference is that although $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_r$ are required to be elements of $\Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}}$, you still have that $f$ is **merely** required to be an element in $\Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

However, virtually the same method used to convert Example 3 into **standard normal form** may be similarly used on the problem presented in (3) above.

Use the change of variables: 
$y_i = x_i - 1, ~: ~i \in \{1,2,\cdots,r\}.$

So, you have **bijected** (3) above into the problem in standard normal form of

$$y_1 + y_2 + \cdots + y_r + f = (8-r) ~: ~y_1,y_2,\cdots,y_r,f \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}. \tag4 $$

Per Stars and Bars theory, (4) above has 
$\displaystyle \binom{[8-r] + r}{r} = \binom{8}{r}~$ solutions.

This implies that

$$f(r) = \binom{8}{r}.$$

This implies that the total number of solutions to the originally posted problem is

$$\sum_{r=0}^5 \left[\binom{5}{r} \times 2^r \times \binom{8}{r}\right].$$

Comment: This is awfully long!

Comment: @Mike Look at the situation from the perspective of the OP (i.e. original poster).  Examine the comments that follow the answer of Rob Pratt.  It is impossible for me to determine what material in my answer may be omitted and still have the analysis in my answer **probably** be crystal clear to the OP.

Comment: Thank you so much! Really appreciate the work you'd put through to make me understand it. It is absolutely clear and you've taught me a lot of new things. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [stars and bars](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) if you introduce a nonnegative integer slack variable $f$ and condition on the number $k\in\{0,\dots,5\}$ of nonzero absolute values among $\{|a|,|b|,|c|,|d|,|e|\}$.  Let $n_k$ be the number of integer solutions to $x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_k + f = 8$ with all $x_i \ge 1$, equivalently the number of nonnegative integer solutions to $x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_k + f = 8 - k$.  Then the desired total is
$$\sum_{k=0}^5 2^k \binom{5}{k} n_k.$$
The $2^k$ arises from the $k$ independent choices of sign, the $\binom{5}{k}$ corresponds to the choice of which $k$ absolute values are nonzero, and $n_k=\binom{(8-k)+(k+1)-1}{(k+1)-1}=\binom{8}{k}$ is the stars and bars formula. The total is
$$1 + 80 + 1120 + 4480+ 5600 + 1792 = 13073.$$

Comment: +1 : This is very nicely reasoned and elegantly presented.  My only criticism is that I had to put my thinking cap on to verify your approach, and I am experienced in Stars and Bars.  I request that you amplify your answer to very carefully explain, with a few examples, why your analysis is accurate/valid.  It is probably also worthwhile to provide Stars and Bars links (perhaps the brillant.org and Wikipedia articles), and to explicitly compute $n_k$.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure I understand where the $2^k$ comes from. I also don't quite understand why there is a $\sum$ in front of the whole expression. Can you please elaborate? Thanks!

Comment: @nich See my answer.